# installing OpenCV on mac osx 10.10.5

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to use OpenCV on python and I am using the command lines on the terminal:

To get homebrew ...

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I believe this works ok.

Then I try to install the dependency gtk+
brew install gtk+

This seems to be ok.

The problem occurs when I install opencv
brew install opencv

I get the return error.... and I just noticed that it is for python2 ... (that could be the issue), but if it is not it seems to be that I have an old mac OS ... is there a way around this?

```
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

Comment: Can you not update your operating systems to a newer version of macOS?

Comment: i think i have to buy it .... am I wrong?

Comment: actually, I think you are onto something )) I will tell you in 5h.

Comment: another solution will be to compile the sources of opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the base module.

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

According the the Apple website you can upgrade for FREE! Upgrading you macOS version should help with this problem.

https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/

Comment: hello! Yes, I did that